# How to set a PFQuery.wherekey to allow for multiple equalTo values?

Tags: swift, parse-server

I want to set a PFQuery's `.whereKey` equal to to an array's values (DB is a parse-server hosted by heroku). Is there anyway to set the `.whereKey` to allow for the value to be equal to any and all of the values within a particular array? For example:

```
let valuesArray = ["Hello", "Hi", "Hey"]
let query = PFQuery(className: "Example")
query.whereKey("values", equalTo: valuesArray)
query.findObjectsinBackground{ (objects, error) in
     //append an array
}
```

I want the query to return all values in the parse-server DB that has "values" equal to any and all of the values in the `valuesArray`. This current set up does not work, so is there anyway to achieve this desired result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you can use `containedIn` instead of `equalTo`:

```
query.whereKey("value of the object", containedIn: valuesArray)
```